# Is this a French equivalent of the English expression "This is what we come to expect from..."?

Tags: sens, expressions

> **Voilà à quoi on reconnaît** un village en plein essor : les femmes ont du caractère !
>
> Somewhat literally: This is what we recognise a fast-growing city by.
>
> More naturally: This is what we come to expect from a fast-growing city.

---

I’m not sure how to intrepret the phrase "Voilà à quoi on reconnaît...". I’d also appreciate an example sentence or two that includes this phrase.

Comment: this is how we recognize ...

Comment: Just a small note: *Village* means the same thing in English, a city would rather be *ville*.

As for the question in your title, I would translate it *Voici ce à quoi on peut s'attendre de...* or *Voici ce qu'on peut espérer de...*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Voici ce à quoi on peut s'attendre* would be the closest answer to the question in your title.

You later mention Recognize and Expect, which have two different meanings.

- Somewhat literally: This is what we recognize a fast-growing city by.  =
  *Voici ce à quoi l'on reconnait* une ville en plein essor.
- More naturally: This is what we come to expect from a fast-growing city.  =  *Voici ce à quoi on s'attend* d'une ville en plein essor.

Comment: +1 for multiple choice with the same semantics

Answer (score 0):

`Voilà à quoi on reconnaît` feels more like something you would say with **enthusiasm**.

Imagine you are a manager and you just saw an employee achieving a particularly difficult task, you turn to the other employees and say:
`Voilà à quoi on reconnaît un bon employé!`

`Voilà à quoi on reconnaît un village en plein essor : les femmes ont du caractère !` = That's how you identify a booming village, ... !

`Voici ce à quoi l'on reconnait une ville en plein essor.` is more neutral, objective. = "You can identify a booming village by ..."